# Cropper crop multiple Images before upload with dropzne js

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, crop, cropper

I'm using Bootstrap with dropzone.js to enable that users can upload images by drag & drop. 
Therefore, I created a drop zone which is working fine including the upload even with multiple images. 
But now, I want to crop the images before I upload them. 
I think the `this.on("added file", function(file){` Event in the init function of dropzone.js is the right place, but I don't know how to convert the files so that I can crop them one by one in a special model and upload the cropped image.

Comment: were you able to find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the uploaded file in dropzone within "addedFile" but if you want to crop images uploaded via dropzone you have to use external lbrary such as [cropperjs](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/). first if you have multi upload in dropzone then give a button to every image or add a click event to every image and pass that file as param to cropperjs.

Comment: I'm already using jquery cropper and as you proposed the addedFile Event, my Problem is that i don't know how to access all added Files. I wan't that the images get edited in a modal. So u drop multiple images, the modal get's open, you crop it and click save, then the next one comes and so on, but how can i access all these images and how do i convert the file to an image which i can crop ?